# How can I use CodePipeline with GitHub Enterprise through Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codepipeline

My source code is in GitHub Enterprise and I want to use that in CodePipeline.

I am using Terraform to provision my CodePipeline, with my source stage looking like this:

```
    name     = "Source"
    category = "Source"
    owner    = "ThirdParty"
    provider = "GITHUB_ENTERPRISE"
```

I'm getting the below error:

> Error: [ERROR] Error updating CodePipeline (tf-test-pipeline): InvalidActionDeclarationException: ActionType (Category: 'Source', Provider: 'GITHUB_ENTERPRISESERVER', Owner: 'ThirdParty', Version: '2') in action 'Source' is not available in region 'AP_SOUTH_1'

What is the issue?

Comment: Are you creating a Connection in your Terraform code as well? In order to connect Github Enterprise to codepipeline you need to have a connection. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/integrations-action-type.html#integrations-source-connections And in the docs, it looks like ap-south-1 is not support for codestar https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/codestar.html

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for quick response. I am not creating a connection for the same , is it necessary to create a codestar for it to work ?